# Error messages when running "drush verify-makefile" on a generated make file

Tags: drush

When running the following command, Drush is printing a number of error messages:

```
drush verify-makefile
```

There is only one make file in document root and it was created with:

```
drush generate-makefile drupal-org.make
```

There were no errors printed with generating the make file. All that is said was:

```
Wrote .make file drupal-org.make                               [ok]
```

I am trying to publish a new Drupal distribution on drupal.org. The particular error messages I am receiving are:

```
The project-level attribute 'custom_download' on project 'datasets' is not allowed. [error]
The project-level attribute 'custom_download' on project 'operations' is not allowed. [error]
The project-level attribute 'custom_download' on project 'quadstat' is not allowed. [error]
```

My guess is that these modules are not published on drupal.org so they can not be included with the distribution. It seems related to this Drupal.org issue: [#1427762](https://www.drupal.org/node/1427762)

Before I went and created these modules on Drupal.org, I was hoping someone could confirm my theory.

Also the syntax generated for the make file seems to follow YAML (a Drupal 8 convention) even though my Drush version is 8.1.2 and my drupalorg_drush version is 7.x-1.x-dev. My Drupal core distribution is 7.44.

I thought it may be helpful to include the make file too.

```
core: 7.44
api: 2
projects:
  admin_menu:
    version: 3.0-rc5
  ctools:
    version: '1.9'
  node_clone:
    version: '1.0'
  features:
    version: '2.10'
  field_group:
    version: '1.5'
  field_permissions:
    version: 1.0-beta2
  filefield_paths:
    version: 1.x-dev
  panels:
    version: '3.5'
  jquery_update:
    version: '2.7'
  libraries:
    version: '2.3'
  mathjax:
    version: '2.4'
  node_export:
    version: '3.1'
  nodeaccess:
    version: '1.4'
  text_with_summary:
    version: '1.0'
  uuid:
    version: 1.0-beta1
  views:
    version: '3.14'
  views_filters_populate:
    version: '1.1'
  shiny:
    version: '1.7'
  datasets:
    type: module
    custom_download: true
  operations:
    type: module
    custom_download: true
  quadstat:
    type: module
    custom_download: true
  libraries:
    SlickGrid:
      directory_name: SlickGrid
      custom_download: true
      type: library
```

There are some other unrelated error messages, but the ones I mentioned are the first that popup.

Thank you for any suggestions provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Not sure if the solution specified here is cosmetic but it did take care of the above question. I am not too familiar with Drupal project packaging.

This particular error was fixed with only making changes to the make file:

- I switched the colons defining Drupal core and the API versions to equals

  I changed the name for SlickGrid library to lowercase("slickgrid")

```
core = 7.44
api = 2
```

The rest of the make file still uses YAML convention. I wonder if that will cause problems down-the-road.